# Highcharts Level 3 drill down

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts

I have a `Highchart` column like this:

- Level-1 contains yearly graph
- Level-2 contains monthly graph where its year
- Level-3 contains animals where its year and month

But when level 3 opened, it shows some data with latest data,
for example: in 2017 January, i have 7 animals. In 2016 January i have 6 animals. And it show me only 7 animals at point 2016 january. Is it possible to show some data from database with 2 conditions?

Please let me know where my mistake is.

Here is a sample of the drill down I am working on:

```
$(function () {

// Create the chart
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Basic drilldown'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Things',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: '2017',
            y: 5,
            drilldown: '2017'
        },
        {
            name: '2016',
            y: 4,
            drilldown: '2016'
        }]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            id: '2017',
            name: '2017',
            data: [{
                name: 'January',
                y: 7,
                drilldown: 'january'
            },{
                name: 'July',
                y: 5,
                drilldown: 'july'
            },
            ],
        },
        {
            id: '2016',
            name: '2016',
            data: [{
                name: 'January',
                y: 6,
                drilldown: 'january'
            },{
                name: 'July',
                y: 3,
                drilldown: 'july'
            },
            ],
        },
        {

            id: 'january',
            data: [['Dogs', 2],
                ['Cows', 1],
                ['Sheep', 2],
                ['Pigs', 1]]
        },{
        id: 'january',
            data: [['Dogs', 3],
                ['Cows', 1],
                ['Sheep', 2],
                ['Pigs', 1]]
        }]
    }
})
});
```

Comment: What is the question then? Are you asking about sql queries or you do not know if the Highcharts config object is correct? If you are asking about Highcharts, it would be easier to tell you what is wrong if you remove php script, and paste the page source or create a live example (jsfiddle/codepen/etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, i forget to change the drilldown id for each year

```
drilldown: {
        series: [{
            id: '2017',
            name: '2017',
            data: [{
                name: 'January',
                y: 7,
                drilldown: '2017-january'
            },{
                name: 'July',
                y: 5,
                drilldown: '2017-july'
            },
            ],
        },
        {
            id: '2016',
            name: '2016',
            data: [{
                name: 'January',
                y: 6,
                drilldown: '2016-january'
            },{
                name: 'July',
                y: 3,
                drilldown: '2017-july'
            },
            ],
        },
        {

            id: '2017-january',
            data: [['Dogs', 2],
                ['Cows', 1],
                ['Sheep', 2],
                ['Pigs', 1]]
        },{
        id: '2016-january',
            data: [['Dogs', 3],
                ['Cows', 1],
                ['Sheep', 2],
                ['Pigs', 1]]
        }]
    }
```